# Issue posting a request with Vue Js and Axios to my Rails Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to post a data(book) to my Rails Api using Vue JS and Axios. Here's the code from my BookList component:

```
<script>
import BookForm from './BookForm';
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data(){
    return{
    books: []
   }
  },
    mounted() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books")
      .then(response => {this.books = response.data})
    },
    components:{
      BookForm
    },
    methods:{
      onClickForm(book){
        console.log(book)
        this.books.push(book)
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books",{book})
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        })
        console.log('Book created')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am able to post the book object but I get an error from the console. It seems my axios post request is not done correctly. Please note that I am sending the book object from my BookForm component emitting an event connected with the onClickForm method. What's wrong in my method? Thanks

This the error I am getting from the console:
[image]

This is the message that i get from the rails api server :
[image]

The book is created but I get a 500 internal error. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are posting fine and this is a server side error. Something related to `book_url`.

Comment: I checked the BooksController but there is no book_url method...can't understand where is the problem

Comment: Does your book object that you send to the server have a book_url property?

Comment: No. Do you think the issue is in the Rails App or in the Vue App?

Comment: I dont think it's Vue.

Comment: Are you sure your rails book_url variable/method rendered correctly? It does look you dont have book_url in rails context